# Shifting a list to the left N times in Prolog

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

I'm trying to make a relation in Prolog `shiftL(L1,N,L2)` that shifts `L1` to the left `N` times (rotationally), and the result is `L2`, so for example `shiftL([1,2,3], 2, [3,1,2])` is true.

I tried the following:

```
shiftL([],N,[]).
shiftL([X|Xs],1,L) :- append(Xs,[X],L).
shiftL([X|Xs],N,L) :- N1 is N-1 , N=\=1 , shiftL(L1,N1,L) , append(Xs,[X],L1).
```

And it works great, but after giving me the result it always keeps doing something else and I get a stack overflow:

```
?- shiftL([1,2,3], 2, L).
L = [3, 1, 2] ;
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

And I have no idea what's causing that. I thought I covered the base case with the second line, and with the `N=\=1` statement.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the relevant program fragment ([failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice)):

```
shiftL([],N,[]) :- false.
shiftL([X|Xs],1,L) :-
   append(Xs,[X],L), false.
shiftL([X|Xs],N,L) :-
   N1 is N-1 ,
   N=\=1,
   shiftL(L1,N1,L), false,
   append(Xs,[X],L1).
```

So essentially the goal `append(Xs,[X],L)` loops. And it loops because neither `Xs` nor `L` is a list - that is a list with fixed length. To see this, consider the recursive goal
`shiftL(L1,N1,L)`.  As you can see in the fragment, `L1` occurs nowhere else. It is thus an uninstantiated variable. And `L` is the variable from the query. So you need to make either `L1` or `L` a list. Like by putting the hidden `append(Xs,[X],L1)` in front.

There is another loop with:

```
?- shiftL([1,2,3],-1,L).
```

I believe you can solve that problem yourself.

For more examples how failure-slices can narrow down problems of non-termination, see [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice).

Comment: Oh I see, so the order of the expressions actually matters. Thank you!